# Python Pandas Increment Counter Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I intend to add a counter column. It should start with a value x and for every new row it should increase incrementally by the same value y.
I already tried to apply this code:

```py
initial_value = x
df["Counter"] = range(initial_value, len(df) + initial_value)
```

But I am not sure how to continue.
Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df["Counter"] = [ i for i in range(x, x+y*(len(df.index)), y) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply :

```
df["Counter"] = list(range(x, len(df)*y+x, y))
```

or Using numpy:

```
df["Counter"] = np.arange(start=x, step=y, stop=len(df)*y+x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to simply loop over the entire dataframe, and to calculate the values like this:

```
df['new_col'] = start_value
for i in range(len(df)):
     df['new_col'][i] = df['new_col'][i-1] + increment_value
```

You can also use apply method to achieve the desired result.

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: start_value + df.index*increment_value)
```